# How Can I Pull The Contacts Records from Salesforce in .NET Web API Connected Application

Tags: c#, .net, salesforce, asp.net-web-api2

I have a connected Salesforce .NET Web Api Application and I'm trying to display all the contacts from that App.

```
public class ContactsController : ApiController
{
    public async Task<Models.Contact> Get()
    {
        var client = await SalesforceService.GetUserNamePasswordForceClientAsync();
        var contacts = await client.QueryAsync<Models.Contact>("SELECT id, FirstName, LastName, Email FROM Contact");
        var sfContact = contacts.Records;

        return sfContacts;
    }
}
```

How do I return sfContacts?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking as the example code already returns the contacts from the api.

Comment: sfContacts is of type Generic List while the Task is of type Models.Contact. I'm not sure what I need to do.

Comment: How are we suppose to know that if it was not explained in the question. clarify the question with what is the problem and maybe we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Update the controller action to return what ever type `sfContacts` is.

For example

```
public class ContactsController : ApiController {
    public async Task<List<Models.Contact>> Get() {
        var client = await SalesforceService.GetUserNamePasswordForceClientAsync();
        var contacts = await client.QueryAsync<Models.Contact>("SELECT id, FirstName, LastName, Email FROM Contact");
        var sfContact = contacts.Records;

        return sfContacts;
    }
}
```

with the assumption being that `contacts.Records` returns a `List<Models.Contact>`

Or better yet use the `IHttpActionResult` abstraction methods of the `ApiController`

```
public class ContactsController : ApiController {
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get() {
        var client = await SalesforceService.GetUserNamePasswordForceClientAsync();
        var contacts = await client.QueryAsync<Models.Contact>("SELECT id, FirstName, LastName, Email FROM Contact");
        var sfContact = contacts.Records
                                .Select(c => new {
                                    c.id,
                                    c.FirstName,
                                    c.LastName,
                                    c.Email
                                });

        return Ok(sfContacts);
    }
}
```

The framework will take the `sfContacts`, whatever it is and serialize it in the response.

Comment: Thank you they both work but they return everything in Contact not just what I selected (Id, FirstName, LastName, Email). It just says <Fax i:nil="true"/>. It adds I:nil="true"/> or false to the fields I didn't select.

Comment: @LauraBejjani obviously. The object is going to have all it properties. They just wont all be populated. That is how objects work

Comment: How do I return only the fields I selected in the select statement?

Comment: @LauraBejjani check update. For the record you are not doing much to help yourself here. This *give me the codz pls* with no research on your part is not going to get you much help on this site. Just my opinion for when you ask questions in the future.

Comment: I tried to do a foreach loop which ended up giving me the same results. I'm new to linq and lamda expressions so I didn't know. I wasn't trying to get the code with no research. This whole project is me experimenting with getting data out of Salesforce. I did get it to work by creating a new Contact class and just putting the fields I wanted in there but your solution is much nicer. Thank you.

Comment: I got error: The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type... I had to add                                                       var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling =                Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
 config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter); to the WebApiConfig.cs file to get it to work. Thanks again for your help